# Invalid column name '*******'

Tags: sql

Format for this query ok, when debugging it I see the value for updating but only show me this message `{"Invalid column name 'Mohannad' "}`, please help me guys

```
UPDATE Employee 
SET Name =Mohannad 
, Age=22 
, GenderID =1 
, CountryID=1 
, Mobile=8765 
FROM Employee 
    INNER JOIN Country ON Employee.CountryID = Country.CountryID 
    INNER JOIN Gender ON Employee.GenderID = Gender.GenderID 
WHERE EmployeeID=1 ; 

SELECT Employee.EmployeeID, Employee.Name, Employee.Age, Employee.GenderID, Gender.GenderName, Employee.CountryID, Country.CountryName, Employee.Mobile 
FROM Employee 
    INNER JOIN Country ON Employee.CountryID = Country.CountryID 
    INNER JOIN Gender ON Employee.GenderID = Gender.GenderID
```

Comment: By the way - how are you generating this command? Had you used a Command with Parameters, you would have avoided this mess, and had much more secure code: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 3):

You need quotes around Mohannad :

```
SET Name='Mohannad'
```

Without quotes, the database engines presumes it's the name of a column.

If you're generating this query in a program, you should use prepared statements, not just put quotes around the names, to avoid bugs and injections.

Comment: SQL like strings like that now?

Answer (score 3):

Try with this code

```
SET Name='Mohannad'
```

Comment: Only putting quotes around your value does not escape the it and leaves your database open to SQL injection. This is the wrong way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Monhannad should be in quotes

```
UPDATE Employee 
SET Name = 'Mohannad', Age=22, GenderID =1, CountryID=1, Mobile=8765 
FROM Employee 
    INNER JOIN Country ON Employee.CountryID = Country.CountryID 
    INNER JOIN Gender ON Employee.GenderID = Gender.GenderID 
WHERE EmployeeID=1 ;
```